# How to build openconnect-gui?

Tags: debian, compiling, openconnect

In OS Windows I used [openconnect-gui](https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect-gui/releases/tag/v1.5.3). After I changed the OS on Debian, I didn't find a version for Debian and I don't understand how to build openconnect-gui for Debian.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as impossible to resolve because the mentioned project seems to be only for Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [application sources you're linking](https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect-gui#supported-platforms):

> Supported Platforms
>
> - Microsoft Windows 7 and newer
> - macOS 10.11 and newer

This isn't made readily available for Linux.

There is no need to compile a GUI for [`openconnect`](https://manpages.debian.org/openconnect/openconnect.8), it's already available as a NetworkManager plugin called [`network-manager-openconnect-gnome`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/network-manager-openconnect-gnome) at Debian. Please note that this is a *plugin* for [NetworkManager](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager), not a stand-alone program with a command directly usable. As such you're supposed to be using NetworkManager, its own applet GUI [`nm-applet`](https://manpages.debian.org/network-manager-gnome/nm-applet.1) provided by [network-manager-gnome](https://packages.debian.org/stable/network-manager-gnome) and add there a new VPN configuration of type openconnect (and subtype Cisco or Juniper/Pulse etc.)

[image]
(picture might be slightly different depending on installed versions)

If for some reason you *really* want to access sources as shipped by Debian, you should first read there: https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage . Package description above has a [link](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/network-manager-openconnect) to sources informations. Providing full informations on how to build with all caveats is out of scope.